# while loop in python gives syntax error

Tags: python, wlst

I am very new to python, this is my first program that I am trying.
This function reads the password from the standard input.

```
def getPassword() :
     passwordArray =[]
         while 1:
                 char = sys.stdin.read(1)
                 if char == '\\n':
                         break
                 passwordArray.append(char)
                 return passwordArray

print (username)
print (URL)
```

getting this error:

```
Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
  (no code object) at line 0
  File "/scratch/aime/work/stmp/wlstCommand.py", line 10
                 while 1: 
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: change while 1 to var = 1
while var == 1  and then run

Comment: @Satya that wouldn't do anything, and would almost certainly be worse than the current version.

Comment: `while True` will behave the same as `while 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your indentation is not correct.  Your `while` should be indented the same as the line above it.

Answer (score 0):

Python uses indentation to "separate" stuff and the thing with that is you need to have the same kind of indentation across the file. Having a fixed kind of indentation in the code you write is good practice. You might want to consider a tab or four spaces(The later being the suggestion in the PEP8 style guide)

Answer (score 0):

Python is sensitive and depended on indentation. If it complains "invalid Format", that is better than "invalid syntax".